# How to create an exe that registers files

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

So basically, one of the projects I'm working on currently is using an old game engine that doesn't have any support anymore, and in order to play you need to register some dlls. Now, the engine comes with a RegisterFiles.exe that will do this for you automatically, but the problem is because the engine is so old, the executable doesn't work for 64 bit computers (at least thats what I'm guessing)..

I'm looking to make a very simple executable that will register about 3-4 dlls/ocxs. I know its possible because the old RegisterFilex.exe program does this with 32 bit operating systems. I have Visual Studio installed on my computer but I haven't used it much. I'm a pretty quick learner so I'm sure if I'm pushed in the right direction, I'll eventually figure it out!

Thanks for any help you guys could provide! If there is an easier alternative rather than creating an exe, I'd like to hear the suggestions! Thanks!

Comment: VBA != VB.NET.  VBA is for Excel, Word, et.al.

Comment: batch file which runs regsvr.exe enough times?

Answer (score 0):

I propose to use the [`Process` Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx) to start regsvr32.exe and silently register those components.

I assume they are 32bit `.dll` and/or `.ocx` components, thus the `\SysWOW64\regsvr32`.exe is used here. Since `regsvr32` is started with the `/s` switch, it will not present any information dialog window. The process itself is started window-less and hidden.

```
Public Class RegComponent
    Public Path As String
    Public IsRegistred As Boolean
End Class

Private RegComponentsList As List(Of RegComponent)

Public Sub RegisterComponents()

    RegComponentsList = New List(Of RegComponent)
    Dim RegSvr32 As String = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows),
                                          "SysWOW64", "regsvr32.exe")

    RegComponentsList.Add(New RegComponent With {.Path = "[Component1Path]", .IsRegistred = False})
    RegComponentsList.Add(New RegComponent With {.Path = "[Component2Path]", .IsRegistred = False})
    RegComponentsList.Add(New RegComponent With {.Path = "[ComponentNPath]", .IsRegistred = False})

    For Each RegComp As RegComponent In RegComponentsList
        RegComp.IsRegistred = RegSvr32RegisterComponent(RegComp.Path, RegSvr32)
    Next

End Sub

Public Function RegSvr32RegisterComponent(ByVal ComponentPath As String, RegSvr32Path As String) As Boolean

    Dim ProcessExitCode As Boolean = False

    Dim psInfo As ProcessStartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo
    psInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    psInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    psInfo.FileName = RegSvr32Path
    psInfo.Arguments = "/s " + ComponentPath
    psInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden

    Dim _Process As Process = New Process() With {.StartInfo = psInfo,
                                                  .EnableRaisingEvents = True,
                                                  .SynchronizingObject = Me}
    _Process.Start()

    'Add an event handler for the Exited event
    AddHandler _Process.Exited,
            Sub(source, e)
                ProcessExitCode = (_Process.ExitCode = 0)
                Console.WriteLine("This process has exited. Code: {0}", ProcessExitCode)
            End Sub

    _Process.WaitForExit()
    _Process.Dispose()
    Return ProcessExitCode

End Function
```